# Navigation Bar Moves Down Page For No Reason

Tags: html, navigation

Im not the greatest with HTML and CSS but I am just confused why this is happening? Im guessing its a width/height problem. I have a page, when you first load it / open it the Nav bar moves down the page, then when you refresh the page it fixes itself and moves to the top of the page?

http://pastebin.com/mXDnuYDw < index.html

http://pastebin.com/ENYkKBgk < stylesheet.css

also the weird thing is when I launch the index from notepad++ it doesn't do the stupid moving thing?

Comment: You should post your code here, in case that link becomes unavailable. Or, you can set up a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So you don't know the answer or...?

Comment: I'm not going to that website. Post the code and I'll take a look. Or at least post direct links to the index.html and stylsheet here. It's best to have the code here so that future visitors to this question can see the code example (posted links become inactive, etc.)

Comment: So you wont help unless you don't have to click like two more times then you would have to?

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues. Try removing HTML and CSS until you have just the navigation left.